# Python 3.7: How do I check if a user input is in a specific format, like "XdY", then if invalid ask again for input?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, dice

I'm trying to write a dice roller as practice. I've tried to look into try, except, while, but neither works as I intend it - before asking if the user wants to continue, I'd want to check if the user input is valid, and if not, return to user_number1. Am I looking at this from the wrong angle? What can I do with this?
Sorry for the possibly stupid question, I'm pretty new to this.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the dice roller!")

def roller():
    user_number1 = input("Please input the dice you want to use in the following format: XdY > ")
    user_number_fin = user_number1.split("d")
    num1 = int(user_number_fin[0])
    num2 = int(user_number_fin[1])

    if num1 == 1:
        result1 = random.randint(num1, num1*num2)
        print("Your roll is: " + str(result1) + " (" + str(num1) + "d" + str(num2) + ")" )

    else:
        dice_number = 1
        list_of_results = []
        while dice_number <= num1:
            result2 = random.randint(num1, num2)
            list_of_results.append(result2)
            dice_number += 1
        print("Your roll is: " + str(sum(list_of_results)) + " (" + str(num1) + "d" + str(num2) + ", " + str(list_of_results)+ ")")


def shouldi():
    roller()
    usercont = input("Do you want to continue? y/n > ")
    while usercont in ["Y", "y"]:
        roller()
        usercont = input("Do you want to continue? y/n > ")

    if usercont in ["N", "n"]:
        print("Thank you for using the dice roller. Bye!")
        quit()
    else:
        print("That is not a valid input.")
        usercont
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: You may want to use regular expressions to check the validity of the input eg.  `user_number_fin = re.match("(\\d?)d(\\d?)",user_number1,re.I)` then you can do a loop: `while not user_number_fin: read again`

Answer (score 0):

Something like below is an alternate approach to using regex. If you're comfortable with regex then I would prefer using that instead of this. This is only an alternate approach.

```
def roller():
user_number1 = input("Please input the dice you want to use in the following format: XdY > ")
if("d" in user_number1):
    if(len(user_number1) == 3):
        user_number_fin = user_number1.split("d")
        num1 = int(user_number_fin[0])
        num2 = int(user_number_fin[1])
 else:
     print("Your input not in valid format. Use the format XdX")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions and write a function that does exactly what you need then you can use it within your `roller()` function:

```
import re

def get_number():
    user_number1 = input("Please input the dice you want to use in the following format: XdY > ")
    user_number_fin = re.match("^(\\d*)d(\\d+)$",user_number1,re.I)
    if not user_number_fin: get_number()
    if user_number_fin.group(1) =='': num1 = 1
    else: num1 = int(user_number_fin.group(1)) 
    num2 = int(user_number_fin.group(2)) 
    if num1>num2:
        print("\n\tSorry--side to roll must be less than the number of sides!!")
        get_number()
    return {'num1':num1,'num2':num2}
```

This can accept `d4` ie taking the default side if not given to be 1, and cannot accept `4d3` ie the side to be rolled must be less than the number of sides present in the dice.